# Icons don't display for some application launchers

Tags: icons

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop for some time now. Since the first day only I have been facing the problem with icon images of some application not appearing up. It causes a lot of inconvenience in locating/identifying an application to be launched.

I have updated my Ubuntu with the latest build today only but still the problem persists.

I have googled around and tried everything relevant available out there but with no success.

Please note that reinstalling Ubuntu is NOT an option right now.

[image: Missing icons]

Comment: sorry , it didnt allow me to upload image.

Comment: I don't think new users can post images. Just post it on imgur or somewhere and link to it, then someone with sufficient privileges can edit your post and include it inline.

Comment: Thank you Scott for suggestion. Here is the link to the image http://imgur.com/02L8i

Comment: apply a different theme and then revert to the default theme

Comment: @green7 Changing themes and then revert back indeed did work, though I had to repeat it a few times. I had to restart the system for launcher icons images to be displayed.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll be posting this as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Apply a different theme and revert to the default one.
- Restart.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having a couple of issues:

- It seems `gnome-settings-daemon` is perhaps not running, which sets which themes to use.
- You seem to possibly be missing the `gnome-icon-theme` and/or `light-themes` packages.

It's hard to say for sure if the second point is true, but this first one definitely is. If you right-click on the background and choose to change the background, do the icons, top bar, and fonts change, if only for a moment? You may be seeing the result of `gnome-settings-daemon` crashing for some reason, and you should file a bug report about it. It cannot be solved simply through askubuntu.

Comment: I changed the background and it would change top bar and fonts but then I applied "green7" suggestion and modified the theme. After a few theme changes and reverts I suddenly got the icon images on desktop items, however the launcher icons images displayed  only after restart. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Drag the icon from unity dash to the launcher.